# Run multiple string replaces with fewer calls to .replace()

Tags: java-6

I'd like to condence the following code into fewer calls to `.replace()`.  It doesn't look like `.replace()` will do this.  Am I right or am I just reading the documentation wrong?

```
public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body.replace("“", "\"").replace("”", "\"").replace("—", "-").replace("’", "'").replace("‘", "'");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `body.replace(['"', '—', '‘'], ['\"', '-', "'"])`.

Comment: Doesn't this call `public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`? As far as I understand from javadocs, your code would be equal to `body.replace("“—‘", "\"-'")`, which is not what is wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. To solve this, you should create a StringBuilder and go through your string 1 character at a time, adding the character to the stringBuilder if it is correct or replacing if it is wrong.